# Okta OpenID Connect w/ Flask app behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, openid, okta

I have a Python Flask app that is successfully running in AWS (Ubuntu) on Gunicorn3 and a Nginx reverse proxy. I added login functionality to the app via Okta openid connect.
OpenID works fine when I run it on my localhost:5000 but gives a 400 error when I run it with Gunicorn3. I changed the redirect URI in the app on the okta dev portal to reflect the URL used to access my site in AWS. Is there something else I need to configure in Ngix to make this work?

The 400 message states the following URL is invalid:

https://dev-xxxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhashme.com%2Foidc%2Fcallback&scope=openid+email+profile&access_....

the redirect_uri is https but the url above indicates "http" Not sure why

The configuration for Nginx is currently:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx.key;
    server_name hashme.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Comment: Upon further review, it seems that Nginx was not the issue but SSL/TLS. I removed the cert / ssl on Nginx and all is working. I thought the issue was the reverse proxy (nginx) but now I just need to figure out how to get OIDC connector in Python working with certs

Comment: I could never get flask-oidc to work with https so I simply updated the config file in nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default) to route all http traffic to https. I updated the app in Okta to http and all is working. Probably not an elegant solution but ...it works